# Is difference-in-difference a valid method to analyze A/B test results?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, difference-in-difference, ab-test

Is a difference-in-difference (DiD) analysis an acceptable method to analyze A/B test results? I know that DiD is more suitable for observational studies (when randomization is not possible), but it seems that it can also be used in a randomized controlled trial (RCT) like an A/B test.

Is this is true?

Comment: Can you outline your motivation in doing so, perhaps with a toy example? Given you mentioned A/B test and randomization, diff-in-diff appears to provide little benefit in general.

Comment: Hi, I don't have a particular motivation in doing so, I am just asking if it's an option to analyze A/B test results using diff-and-diff. My question comes from this paper of H. Varian: https://www.pnas.org/content/113/27/7310

As you can see, Diff-and-diff it is a method more used in observational studies, when randomization it's not feasible. But, I wonder if it could be used in RCT's since diff-and-diff involves control/treatment variants, according to Varian, in D&D "we have two groups, the treated and the untreated, and two time periods, before treatment and after treatment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of cases where DID is preferred to the usual treatment-control means difference (MD).

First, DID is more efficient (i.e., has smaller variance) than MD when autocorrelation for the outcome exceeds $\frac{1}{(m+1)}$, where $m$ is the number of pre-treatment periods. This is because the difference in two random variables has a higher variance than that of one of these variables alone unless those variables are sufficiently highly correlated.

Second, sometime randomization fails for some reason and there are differences between the two groups. This can happen where you have randomization at geographic level (say DMAs in Varian's marketing example), and it is hard to achieve balance, especially if there are few treated regions. DID can handle that as long as the difference is time-invariant.

Comment: (+1) I also found this online [post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/https-medium-com-kcpub21-did-analysis-a8317c5aa5e6) an interesting read.